# Store representations in SQL rather than whole strings?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I want to mark my users with one out of four static strings: **indestructible, unstoppable, superefficient** and **megafantastic**.
Would it be faster and more efficient to store a one char representation of the string rather than the whole string? Sort of like a key<->value mapping. The DB would only need to match one letter instead of a whole string when I do a search.

In the DB these words would only be represented as **i,u,s** and **m**. On the users profile I print **indesctuctible** if I get an **i**, **unstoppable** if I get a **u** etc.

Do I actually speed up anything by doing like this or is it just unnecessary work?
What if I have 10 more of these representations?

Comment: Good answers all around. *I can see clearly now...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about database design, you should have a [normalized design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Create a lookup table id/name, store the id value in your user table (use something like a tinyint).

```
ID  Name
1   indestructible
2   unstoppable
3   superefficient
4   megafantastic
```

This way you can query the database directly for the string.

If you cache this table, you will not be hitting the database for these values, and you will only be storing a small amount of data per user (not to mention transfer less data over the wire) - these all translate to better performance on your DB.

Comment: +1 - And by `id` I think @oded means an numerical `int` or `smallint` value

Comment: @Oded: But will that be more performant? I think that's his question.

Comment: @codeulike - less data to transfer will mean better performance.

Comment: Yes it will be better performing - instead of a 15-20 byte varchar per row you will store 4 byte `int` or 2 byte `smallint`.  Less data = faster.

Comment: @oded/@JNK: I think you're right in this case, but less data doesn't always mean faster if its offset with more processing. But there are very good reasons for normalizing other than performance, so I guess its a moot point here anyway.

Comment: @Code - well to your point, it's also faster to compare numericals as opposed to strings as well.  This is better in both regards.

Comment: You do not normalise for speed benefits, you do it for data consistency.

The performance implications are not clear-cut. If you do the join for every query, it will probably be slower - best case it's the same size result but the engine needs to do an additional join. Reducing page count might make the database perform better overall if the table is very large and/or you don't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you might see a little performance boost. That said, it may not be worth it if you compromise your database design. This is a [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) question. Without knowing how you're planning on using the data it is difficult to say exactly how you should structure your data.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a waste of time. Beware of micro-optimizations. For such a reduction you would loose all meaning in the database for that column, loose the flexibility to have values that start with same letter, have to modify your DAL to pass in just the first letter when given a whole word.

I would normally index the column and leave it as full strings. If that was the bottleneck in your system then your writing the fastest, most efficient programs in the world and you don't need my humble advice anyway ;-).

Comment: +1 for taking account of the faffing about involved to get a very small performance increase. Whether it should be done from a normalisation pov is a different question.

Comment: *loose the flexibility to have values that start with same letter*.  On smaller systems, would this out weight the benefits in @Oded's answer?

Comment: The lookup code table is very common. A lot of projects use then enforce referential constraints which can be good thing. You can do the same thing using column constraints however but in both cases the db will check the constraint on insert and update. I'm not sure why the strings need to be in db at all if, like you say, they are static, then you could just store an int in the column without the lookup table. That is how enums are often stored and retrieved from databases.

Comment: @Niklas - if you use an `int` instead of a `char` or `varchar` you won't have this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should make your code faster, using a code 1,2,3,4 would be even fastest for 2 reasons

1) It takes less time to compare an int(that can be compared in 1 CPU cycle) than comparing two strings. Even 1 char may take more cycles because it needs to work if 'A' equals 'a' etc.

2) it takes up less space in the table, in a DB the smaller your rows are the faster your DB will be becaus SQL will be able to fit more rows onto a page.

You may need to have a serious number of users to notice the difference, but it would defenitley be good practice to store codes instead of values.

Regards GJ

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lookup table and which has a fk into the main table

```
Character
------------
CharacterID
Name
ProfileID int (FK)

Profile
--------
ProfileID
ProfileDesc
```

where profile table is

```
ProfileID, ProfileDesc
----------------------
1        , indestructable
2        , ...
```

This would allow you to add a smaller more efficient index onto the ProfileID in the Character table

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to maximize your performance and don't care about normalizing this data (which is almost always the best option), you could store those 4 attributes as bits:

```
CREATE TABLE <name> (
    <other fields>
    isIndestructible bit, 
    isUnstoppable bit
    isSuperefficient bit
    isMegafantastic bit
)
```

It's bad practice in that you'll be SOL if you decide to add "isMagnificent" or change "isIndestructable" to "isResilient", but if you've really just got 4 attributes you're tracking, 4 bits are hard to beat.